# Magento - issues with recurring profiles and coupons

Tags: coupon, billing, recurring

I have a subscription based site where we want to offer the first month for free using a coupon code. The problem is that when you place an order with the coupon code, Magento automatically applies that coupon (so to say) to every subsequent billing month.

Does anyone know which files would control this so that I can change this behavior?

Another solution may be to use the trial period feature, however this won't let you use 0 as a price and also charges tax on the full amount even if set to $0.01.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried restricting the coupon to be used once per customer? Also you could change your tax configuration to apply the tax after discount.

Comment: Yes, I have tried restricting the coupon for once per customer, that does not work.  The only thing I see in the tax configuration is "Calculate tax off subtotal only" which is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below for the setting I was referring to to change the order of discount and taxation: `System > Configuration > Tax > Tax Calculation > Apply Customer Tax` and also `Apply Discount on Prices` 
[image: tax settings]

Comment: Please see the settings I have here:  http://postimg.org/image/3rmomvf2z/ It is still applying tax to the full amount and not the trial period amount.

Comment: Also, just to not, the issue with the tax happens when using a trial period amount for recurring items.  It works fine when coupons are applied