# How do I fix "Payment profile is invalid: Trial billing amount is wrong." when trying to check out with recurring profile with free trial period?

Tags: cart, recurring, billing

I set up a daily (for testing) recurring profile, with a free trial period of 3 days, using the following settings:

[image]

Then I test (my store is connected to PayPal in sandbox mode) as a user, add the product to my cart, my total is $0 as expected, with daily subscription fully described, but when I click "Proceed to Checkout", the cart page refreshes with a red error box above my cart items that says, "Payment profile is invalid: Trial billing amount is wrong." Am I setting something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a free trial by setting "Trial Billing Amount" to 0. 0 is not allows for that setting, and causes the error message mentioned.

I don't yet know how to create a free trial period with native magento (without paying for some 3rd party extension). [One person tried](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/magento-issues-with-recurring-profiles-and-coupons) a coupon code, but that discount continued to be applied for all recurring billings.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trial billing frequency and the cycles from the form and save it.